# Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I am using Windows 7, php 5.3.5 and WAMP server.  I have two php files: trigger.php and background.php.
I want to run background.php as a background process. I have to call this file from trigger.php. To accomplish this I used below method.
I included following code in trigger.php to make background.php to process in background.

```
$handle = popen('start /b C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe     C:\wamp\www\email3.php','r');
```

in background.php I have the follwing code to connect to database.

```
$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=tagbase user=postgres password=postgres";
```

now, on parsing this line am getting the follwing error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\wamp\www\background.php on line 3 Call Stack: 0.0002 322792 1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\background.php:0

By searching in in the internet I found some solutions, and made changes as recommended below in php.ini,

```
uncommented, extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll,
uncommented, extension=php_pgsql.dll,
uncommented, extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/",
```

also I do have php_pdo_pgsql.dll and php_pgsql.dll files in `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/` folder.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: do you enable this extensions in php.ini and restart server ?)

Comment: yes Mr.BattleBit. i enabled. but same error.

Comment: in your apache config file put this Loadfile "C:\php\libpq.dll". Also check the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.setup.php

Answer (score 25):

**Apache 2.2.X configuration**

Add the next line to the Apache 2.2.x httpd.conf configuration:

```
LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/{version}/bin/libpq.dll"
```

Above line must be entered before the next line.

*`LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.2.11/php5apache2_2.dll"`*

**PHP 5.2.X Configuration**

Enable the following two lines in the php.ini configuration file. By 'Enable' i mean,  remove trailing ; (semicolon). By these, you un-comment the line.

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

**Restart WAMP**

Test by adding this in your index.php

```
echo extension_loaded('pgsql') ? 'yes':'no';
```

(source: http://www.plaatsoft.nl/wamp-postgresql-integration/)

Comment: hi Mr.jordi kroon, as you suggested when i included the following in httpd.conf file :  lineLoadFile “C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/libpq.dll”, my server itself is not restarting properly. And LoadModule php5_module “c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/php5apache2_2.dll” already present in that configuration file.

Comment: The load file.. should point to the libpq.dll. Check the path.

Comment: i checked. path is correct. LoadFile "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/libpq.dll",since in the path "Program Files" contains space ,am i suppose to escape that space.?

Comment: No, since there are quotes arround them. Check your apache error logs.

Comment: apache error logs also contains same error:PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\wamp\www\background.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\background.php:0
[Wed Feb 13 14:50:53 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico

Comment: This did it for me, thanks. Some users may need to beware of the quotes Jordi has used in his answer; use these: " "

Comment: Thanks, quotes changed.

Comment: Just so that anyone else reading this doesn't mess up: on Windows you need forward slashes to make it work, so :

LoadFile "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\{version}\bin\libpq.dll"

Answer (score 4):

if we install WAMP server, we will get two php.ini files. 
one in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5 and another in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin.

**if we execute a php file from browser, then php.ini file in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin will be referred.
if we execute a php file from command line, then php.ini file in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5 will be referred.**

what ever the changes i made enable/disable the dll in PHP->PHP extensions,all the changes will be saved in 
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\php.ini file. but C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini file remains unchanged.

for my problem, i made the following changes

```
uncommented, extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll,
uncommented, extension=php_pgsql.dll,
uncommented, extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/",
```

in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.ini file. Now its working good. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case with 
Apache/2.4.10
PHP Version 5.4.32
PostgeSQL 9.3
I added libpq.dll into Apache httpd.conf from PHP catalog because Apache refused to start with libpq.dll from PostgreSQL 9.3