# Undefined function sqlsrv_connect()- Apache2.4

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\SQLI\SQL_CON.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\SQLI\SQL_CON.php on line 4**

I already add this to php.ini file :

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

my simple code is :

```
<?php
$servername="JOSEPHP-JOSEPHP\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorks2014");
$con = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);
if($con) {
    die ("Connect is ok: ".connect_error);
}
else {

    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just like the error says, this `sqlsrv_connect` function doesn't exist.

Comment: You also have to install [Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

Comment: You also have to install [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) to actually get the 2 dlls you need

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: I did it. But still the same ..

Comment: Then in that case maybe you edited the wrong `php.ini` you need to edit the one in the `\apache\bin\` folder and not the one in the php folder, that one is only used by PHP CLI

Comment: And place those dll's into the `/php/ext` folder so they can be found

Comment: There is no php.ini file in apache\bin. Only in php ?? I add this files in that location and then what ?

Comment: run `phpinfo()` to find out php.ini loction

Comment: Thanks to all. I fix it will your help . I also had and Login fail error and fix it :))