# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() using WAMP and php 7.1.6

Tags: sql-server, wamp, php-7.1

First things first, I read and tried stuff I found online even from this website, but can't get it to work.

I have an **SQL SERVER 2014** running on **Windows Server 2012**, there I have a **WAMP 64 bits** running **Apache** on **PHP 7.1.6** and need to connect to the Database, apparently the extension is not loaded because I'm getting the ***undefined function error***.

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $APIDBSERVER, $connection);

What I've done so far:

- Installed **Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server**
- Downloaded **PHP SQL Driver 4.0** and moved php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll to **/ext**
- Added them to **php.ini**:
  extension=**php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll**
  extension=**php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll**

Apparently the PDO also needs php_pdo.dll which WAMP doesn't have and I haven't found where to download it from, so **I'm using the standard non-PDO approach**

- Recently even tried enabling odbc extensions which were disabled:

extension=php_odbc.dll

extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll

I access the php.ini through the WAMP menu so I know I'm editing the right one, restarted the server several times trying different things but I've run out of ideas.

Can you please help me?

**EDIT**:
PHP error log indicates the modules couldn't be found, but if I check that path they're right there, copy&pasted filenames into php.ini.

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.6/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.1.6/ext/php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll' - The
>   specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0

**EDIT 2:**
Tried downgrading to 7.0.20 and get the same error, so the php.ini is fine, it just won't load them for a reason, will try to download ODBC 13.1 maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)

Answer (score 1):

Each PHP version might require a different version of the Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server.

The link below shows compatibility between PHP and MS SQLSRV versions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way WAMPServer is configures, NTS extensions do not run.

So change your process just a little and use the Thread safe dll's instead.

Comment: Gonna try that thanks.
EDIT: I think it works, not getting the undefined function error so guess it's a yes, still have to check if it connects but sir I owe you a coffee!