# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\Project\Demo.php on line 4

Tags: php, sql-server, database

MS SQL server Connection to PHP Using Wamp Server, I Will follow this Step :

```
My System Windows 7 64-bit
installed Wamp Server 64-bit
SQLSRV32.EXE installed in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.31\ext
```

wamp server PHP.ini file give extension

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
```

Demo.php`

```
<?php
$serverName = "ZALA-PC\EURASIAN";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "Demo", "UID"=>"sa" , "PWD"=>"stcare@1");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you restart the server? Post your `phpinfo` or `php -i`

Comment: Does it work in 32-bit mode? Maybe you installed the wrong version of the driver.

Comment: This appears to be a SQL Server question, unrelated to MySQL.

Comment: wamp server 32- bit is not available on site http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: sql server driver provide sqlsrv32.exe for php 5.6.31 on microsoft site.

Comment: any update in server file i have restart server every time.

Comment: please, Help me to this Problem Solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22015179/1255289)

Comment: I have find Solution. download 64 bit sqlsrv after works complete.

Comment: Thank you,All of you Give me suggestion and Help