# Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in php 5.6.25

Tags: php, sql-server

*OS*: Windows 8.1

*Web Server*: WAMPSERVER 3.0.6

*PHP Version*: 5.6.25

*Goal*: To establish MYSQL Database connection using PHP

What has been done:

- Downloaded `SQLSRV` Drivers (`SQLSRV32.EXE`)
- Copied files `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` and `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` to the directory `"C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext"`
- `extension_dir = "c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/"`
- Added the following lines to the dynamic extensions part in the `php.ini` file:

  - `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`
  - `extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`
- Restarted Web Server

But: `phpinfo()` is not listed in `sqlsrv()`

Code:

```
$myServer = "(local)";
$myUser = "sa";
$myPass = "pass";
$myDB = "example_db";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$myDB, "UID" => $myUser, "PWD" => $myPass);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($myServer, $connectionInfo);
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
C:\wamp64\www\optimum_p\common\dbconnect.php on line 6
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015179/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect

Comment: I tried but not working

Comment: Problem is WAMP. Uninstalled the WAMP. And installed XAMPP. 
The problem has solved.

Answer (score 1):

As per OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377340/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect-in-php-5-6-25#comment81731397_47377340):

The problem was WAMP, to fix the problem:

1. uninstall WAMP
2. install XAMPP

Problem solved.