# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() when connecting Microsoft SQL management studio 2014 with php

Tags: php, database, ssms, ssms-2014

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect().

```
$serverName = "serverName";

$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "databaseName");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";
} else {
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Check your php.ini and make sure you have enabled it ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043692/7223704

Comment: have you enabled downloaded and enabled the sql_srv extension?