# problems importing sqlsrv drivers to fix the error:Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql

I have looked at a couple other questions on stackoverflow to fix my problems

[Cannot Call function sqlsrv_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776078/cannot-call-function-sqlsrv-connect)

[Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849010/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-pg-connect?rq=1)

but can't seem to find my problem. I have downloaded the drivers from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 followed by copying them to my php files in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\ext and C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.4\ext and made extensions in my C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\bin file. After this i still get the same errors.

[image]

[image]

I did import the php_sqlsrv drivers both in php7.0.4 and php5.6.19 files to b sure.

Comment: Did you restart the server after you imported/copied the files and made changes to the ini?

Comment: Yes i did, didn't fix the problem :/